# Extract url from hyperlink using google sheets api

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-sheets-api

[image]

I have several columns in a google sheet containing only hyperlinks and need to be able to extract the url from the string. I request the sheet using googleapis npm package and the hyperlinks come in as strings.

Figured it out, just set the `valueRenderOption` to 'FORMULA' and returns as `=HYPERLINK('someurl.com', 'Display Text')`
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueRenderOption#ENUM_VALUES.FORMATTED_VALUE

Comment: What does your code look like that doesn't work? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40612615/how-to-fetch-the-hyperlink-from-google-sheets